# What is refsrc in URLs?

Tags: url, parameters

What is the refsrc parameter in URLs for? There is a URL that is being circulated with our domain, but not sure if this is a safe thing.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the application/website receiving request with that parameter. I've seen that parameter name used to embed the current page for the link. (I believe I saw that on facebook links?)
In that way when the link is followed, the next app/web site is able to know where the link is coming from if the information is not in the HTTP headers due to redirections or similar situations.

I don't believe it's a standard though.